# Registration: Parent and child

Tags: registration, simplicity

currently working on redesigning a registration that serves three different audiences:

1. Parent and Child
2. Self (adult)
3. Third party paying on behalf of someone else

I am less worried about in which context, what information to display for each audience for there is research behind that, this is a general ux question.

**The question I have is how to introduce three different forms for three different audiences for a registration? Or is there a simpler UX that allows 1 form to serve all 3?**  One of the key issues is that the first option, means you will create an account for yourself, the parent, and one for your child. As opposed to the second option you will only be creating an account for yourself and should only be exposed to language around that.

I currently have mapped out their form depending on which bullet they choose to begin with liked i have mocked up below.

[image]   [image]

Comment: I think what you have there is fine. Wait until a bullet has been selected and display the corresponding form to the user. Using three forms altogether may make it daunting and cause confusion to some users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do like the solution shown in the question. Nice and simple.

It is however worth considering what happens if a user changes their response to the 'account type' question, having already completed some or all of the form below. You should avoid wiping the information they've already provided. I would keep the common fields in place (I assume some fields are relevant to all account types) and only show/hide those fields that are affected by the new 'account type' setting.

One potential alternative might be to collect the common information first, then ask the user to choose an account type and subsequently collect the additional information relevant to that type.

Comment: Discussion over marketing and business rules actually resulted ins something similar to your last option. Getting the most basic info for a lead was a high priority.  Now it is in the process "the abandons" in forced to providing that information upon returning. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simpler, imperative (as opposed to declarative) statements:

- Create an account for myself
- Create an account for my child
- Create an account for someone else (not my child)

Alternatively it could be phrased in second person:

- Create an account for yourself
- Create an account for you child
- Create an account for someone else (not your child)

These options could be expressed as radio buttons or push buttons (or even links).  Throughout out subsequent pages of the process it would be good to remind them what they're doing in the header ("Creating account yourself").